# Modify the norm of a vector

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I have a vector $\vec{V} = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
a\\
b\\
c\\
\end{array}
\right)$

And I want a vector $\vec{W}$ that is the same like $\vec{V}$ but with a norm of x (x is a number...)

So what are the coordinates of $\vec{W}$ ?

Comment: If $\vec{V}$ has norm $\alpha = ||\vec{V}||_2$. Then take $\vec{W} = \frac{x}{\alpha} \vec{V} = (\frac{x}{\alpha} a, \frac{x}{\alpha}  b ,\frac{x}{\alpha}  c )^T$. This is simply because $\vec{V}/\alpha$ is the unit vector of $\vec{V}$.

Comment: Of course... thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $w=(\frac{ax}{||v||},\frac{bx}{||v||}, \frac{cx}{||v||})$ where $||v||= \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$